# How to handle error in Retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, error-handling, retrofit2

I want to handle error in Retrofit 2.0

Got e.g. `code=404` and `body=null`, but `errorBody()` contains data in `ErrorModel` (`Boolean status` and `String info`).

This is `errorBody().content`: `[text=\n{"status":false,"info":"Provided email doesn't exist."}]`.

How can I get this data?

Thank for helping me!

This is my code for Retrofit request:

```
ResetPasswordApi.Factory.getInstance().resetPassword(loginEditText.getText().toString())
    .enqueue(new Callback<StatusInfoModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<StatusInfoModel> call, Response<StatusInfoModel> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                showToast(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.new_password_sent));
            } else {
                showToast(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.email_not_exist));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<StatusInfoModel> call, Throwable t) {
            showToast(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong...");
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you put some code

Comment: This code you mean?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to get data when error response comes (**typically a response code except 200**) you can do it like that in your `onResponse()` method:

```
if (response.code() == 404) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    YourErrorPojo pojo = new YourErrorPojo();
    try {
         pojo = gson.fromJson(response.errorBody().string(), YourErrorPojo.class);
         Toast.makeText(context, pojo.getInfo(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) { 
      // handle failure at error parse 
  }
}
```

When generating `YourErrorPojo.class` do following steps :

1. Go to [Json Schema 2 Pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)
2. Paste your example `Json`, and select source type **Json** , annotation **Gson**
3. Your example `Json` is : `{"status":false,"info":"Provided email doesn't exist."}`
4. Click **Preview** and it will generate your `Pojo` class for you.

Add this to your `build.gradle` : `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'`

I used `Gson` in this solution but you can get your `Json` string using: `response.errorBody().string()`

Comment: I tried this code:
`Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();`
`StatusInfoModel error = new StatusInfoModel();`
`try { error = gson.fromJson(response.errorBody().string(), StatusInfoModel.class);`
`showToast(getApplicationContext(), error.getInfo());`
`} catch (IOException e) { // handle failure to read error }`, but there is an error: `Class must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method`.

Comment: @y07k2 Can you provide screenshot and i will look it ?

Comment: https://s32.postimg.org/eww0vfotx/error.png. When I remove `else` statement error disappears.

Comment: @y07k2 Ah i see your error, because i missed one "}" , i added it to my answer. Please look edited answer.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you! :) P.S. Any idea how can I simplify this (I mean put into method and call it in a different places)?

Comment: @y07k2 if you sure you getting same response when 404 occurred , you can simplfy it. In my api when i get a response except 200 i am getting same response like : `{
  "code" : 401,
  "message": "Authorization has been denied"
}`

Answer (score 6):

Retrofit doesn't see 404 as a failure, so it will enter the onSuccess.

`response.isSuccessful()` is true if the response code is in the range of 200-300, so it will enter the else there.

```
if (response.isSuccessful()) {
    showToast(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.new_password_sent));
} else {
    // A 404 will go here

    showToast(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.email_not_exist));
}
```

However since your response was not successful, you do not get the response body with `.body()`, but with `errorBody()`, errorBody will filled when the request was a success, but `response.isSuccessful()` returns false (so in case of a status code that is not 200-300).

Comment: Yes, I know that it can be done like this but I don't want to type `String errorMsg` every time, when I can (at least I believe I can) get if from `errorBody()`.

Comment: `errorBody` is for when an error occurs, which does not apply in case of 404. 404 is seen as a success

Comment: So that is weird. Why I receive this data in `errorBody()`, not in `body()`?

Comment: My bad. `errorBody` contains the response if the response was not successful. So in case there was no error, but the status code was not 200-300. Status code 404 will have the response in errorBody as you said

Comment: "response.isSuccessful() is true if the response code is in the range of 200-300"
To be precise: http responses beginning with 2XX are successes, 3XX redirections, 4XX client-side errors and 5XX server-side errors.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this library [Retrobomb](https://github.com/LegalShield/retrobomb), you don't have to serialize at that level.
it's easy to use and customize. It supports annotation for each error type or error code.
If you prefer you can unwrap all errors and handle by your self.

```
@ErrorMapping(code = 401, errorType = Unauthorized.class)
@PATCH("/v1/widgets/{id}")
  Single<Widget> updateWidget(@Path("id") String id, @Body Widget widget);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data when error response comes (typically a response code except 200) you can do it like that in your `onResponse()` method:

```
override fun onResponse(call: Call<LoginData>?, response: Response<LoginData>?) {
    if (response != null) {
        if (response.code() == 200 && response.body() != null) {
            val loginData = response.body()
            if (loginData != null) {
                //Handle success case...
            }
        } else if (response.code() == 401) {
            val converter = ApiClient.getClient()?.responseBodyConverter<ErrorResponseData>(
                ErrorResponseData::class.java,
                arrayOfNulls<Annotation>(0))
            var errorResponse: ErrorResponseData? = null
            errorResponse = converter?.convert(response.errorBody())
            if (errorResponse != null) {
                //Handle Error case..
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Kotlin:**

Just follow this code to convert your **errorBody** to your response:

```
if(response.isSuccessful){
     val data = response.body()!!
               
 }else {
    val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

    try {
        var pojo = gson.fromJson(
            response.errorBody()!!.string(),
            CommentResponse::class.java)
            Log.e("ERROR_CHECK","here else is the error$pojo")

     } catch (e: IOException) {
           // handle failure at error parse
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do in the following way

```
fun parseErrorBody(readText: String?): String {
    if (!readText.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        val result = Gson().fromJson(readText, AppError::class.java)//AppError can be your server error response model
        return result.errors?.get(0)?.message ?: Constants.EMPTY_STR
    }
    return ""
}
```

and calling code

```
    if(response.isSuccessful){}//handle success response
else{
    parseErrorBody(response.errorBody()?.charStream()?.readText())
}
```