# Getting json from retrofit's response errorBody

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, gson

I am struggling with retrofit. When I post a request in my browser i get such a request: [image]

And that's what I expect. However, when I try to parse this in my app I kept getting responses as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598707/gson-throwing-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array) thread. I've found tried to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304316/how-to-handle-error-in-retrofit-2-0) solution, but my `errorBody` does not even resemble the answer from my browser:
[image] 
How can I get this JSON?

Just in case this is my response handler code:

```
void handleResponse(Response response){
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.empty_list_tv);
    if(response.isSuccessful())
        textView.setText(response.toString());
    else {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = gson.fromJson(
                response.errorBody().toString(),
                ErrorResponse.class);
        textView.setText(response.errorBody().toString());
    }
}
```

And my `ErrorResponse`:

```
public class ErrorResponse {
    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("error")
    private Error error;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public Error getError() {
        return error;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `response.errorBody().toString(),` a JSON?

Comment: No. At least I don't recognize it is: "okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@f0473b9"

Comment: You are trying to construct `errorResponse` from GSON's fromJson which expects a JSON. Do you see where you are doing wrong?

Comment: Ah. That's what you mean. I see I've used `toString()` instead of `string()`. When I evaluate `response.errorBody().string()` I get `{"error":{"message":"Not Found","error":{"status":404}}}` which is what I want. I'll post your answer to mark problem as solved. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad I could help!!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You are using `toString()` in GSON's fromJson which is not a JSON content. Replace your `toString()` as `string()` which will give you the JSON body.
Also make sure to use the `string()` method only once and save the response in a variable, because it will return empty string if you used it again.

Comment: this worked, but if I called the `string()` method second time it will return empty string

Comment: @KhalidTaha What do you exactly mean when you say you are calling the method second time? Can you elaborate a bit

Comment: I mean if you call `string()` method for the first time it will return the correct string, but if you called it another once, it will return empty string.

Comment: Care to elaborate or update my answer with valid explanation for that? It might help someone else looking for the answer @KhalidTaha

Comment: Thanks for the answer. using ```string()``` works but I had to surround it in a try catch.

Comment: If you need to use response.errorBody().string() more than once, check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73857446/9952567

Answer (score 9):

you use string(), not toString()

```
 ErrorResponse errorResponse = gson.fromJson(
                response.errorBody().toString(),
                ErrorResponse.class);
```

to

```
ErrorResponse errorResponse = gson.fromJson(
                response.errorBody().string(),
                ErrorResponse.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin

Parse the error body

```
val errorResponse = Gson().fromJson(response.errorBody()?.charStream(),ErrorResponse::class.java)
```