# Using Retrofit i want to access the userId from the JSON Response (a value from an array inside object)

Tags: android, json, api, gson, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit for the first time. So don't mind the silliness please.
I have 2 problems:

Problem 1. How to get a value for the key "userId" from the API JSON response. (When isSuccessful is true) Following is the response from the API.

[image: API Response]

I am able to get the userId from the following messy code, kindly show me a better way:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                        JSONArray userInfoObject = jsonObject.getJSONArray("userInfo");
                        JSONObject userIDObject = userInfoObject.getJSONObject(0);
                        Long userId = userIDObject.getLong("userId");
```

Problem 2:
onResponse when isSuccessful is false, the response.body is appearing null. So how do i access the API JSON response in this case. However on using the Okhttp logging i find the okhttp logs the response in this case as well but the Retrofit callback shows response.body() as null.

[image: okhttp logs response but retrofit shows response body as null]

**Interface Class**

```
public interface UserInfoClient {

@Headers("x-st-diagnostics-callerid: DKAPP-RETROFIT")
@POST("/api/User/")
Call<UserInfoModel> createUser(
        @Header("x-st-diagnostics-correlationid") String uniqueID,
        @Body UserInfoModel userInfo);
```

}

**DataModel**

```
public class UserInfoModel {


private List userInfo;
private String statusMessage;
private Integer statusCode;
private Long userId;
private String userFullName, userPassword, userName, userEmail, userMobileNumber, userWebsite, userDateOfBirth, userProfileText, userProfileDisplayPhoto, userProfileCoverPhoto;

public UserInfoModel(Long userId, String userFullName, String userPassword, String userName, String userEmail, String userMobileNumber, String userWebsite, String userDateOfBirth, String userProfileText, String userProfileDisplayPhoto, String userProfileCoverPhoto) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.userFullName = userFullName;
    this.userPassword = userPassword;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.userEmail = userEmail;
    this.userMobileNumber = userMobileNumber;
    this.userWebsite = userWebsite;
    this.userDateOfBirth = userDateOfBirth;
    this.userProfileText = userProfileText;
    this.userProfileDisplayPhoto = userProfileDisplayPhoto;
    this.userProfileCoverPhoto = userProfileCoverPhoto;
}

public Long getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public List getUserInfo() {
    return userInfo;
}

public Integer getStatusCode() {
    return statusCode;
}

public String getStatusMessage() {
    return statusMessage;
}
```

}

Activity.java

```
public class ActivityUserInfo extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "ActivityUserInfo";
private EditText etUserId, etFullName, etPassword, etUsername, etEmail, etMobileNumber, etWebsite, etDob, etProfileTxt, etDispPhoto, etCoverPhoto;
private Button btnUpload;
public static Retrofit retrofit;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: begins");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_info);

    etUserId = findViewById(R.id.et_userID);
    etFullName = findViewById(R.id.et_fullName);
    etPassword = findViewById(R.id.et_password);
    etUsername = findViewById(R.id.et_username);
    etEmail = findViewById(R.id.et_email);
    etMobileNumber = findViewById(R.id.et_mobileNumber);
    etWebsite = findViewById(R.id.et_website);
    etDob = findViewById(R.id.et_dob);
    etProfileTxt = findViewById(R.id.et_profileBio);
    etDispPhoto = findViewById(R.id.et_profilePhoto);
    etCoverPhoto = findViewById(R.id.et_coverPhoto);
    btnUpload = findViewById(R.id.btn_uploadUserInfo);

    btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            UserInfoModel userInfo = new UserInfoModel(
                    Long.parseLong(etUserId.getText().toString()),
                    etFullName.getText().toString(),
                    etPassword.getText().toString(),
                    etUsername.getText().toString(),
                    etEmail.getText().toString(),
                    etMobileNumber.getText().toString(),
                    etWebsite.getText().toString(),
                    etDob.getText().toString(),
                    etProfileTxt.getText().toString(),
                    etDispPhoto.getText().toString(),
                    etCoverPhoto.getText().toString()
            );

            sendNetworkRequest(userInfo);
        }
    });

}

private void sendNetworkRequest(UserInfoModel userInfo){
    Log.d(TAG, "sendNetworkRequest: begins");
    //Create okhttp client
    OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    //Adding logging interceptor tot he okHttp client
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    //set logging interceptor properties
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    //To redact a header from logging
    logging.redactHeader("Content-Type");
    //Disable logging interceptor in mode other than DEBUG.
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        //Adding logging interceptor to the okHttpClient using okHttp client builder (conditional for debug only)
        okHttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(logging);
    }

    //Create Retrofit Instance
    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://abc.ett.io")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClientBuilder.build());

    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    // Get client and call object for the request
    UserInfoClient client  = retrofit.create(UserInfoClient.class);

    String  uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString(); //UUID for the header
    Call<UserInfoModel> call = client.createUser(uniqueID, userInfo);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<UserInfoModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UserInfoModel> call, Response<UserInfoModel> response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "1. onResponse: body: " + response.body() + "\n message: " + response.message()
                    + "\n code: " + response.code() + "\n headers: " + response.headers() + " errorBody: " + response.errorBody()
                    + "\n isSuccessful: " + response.isSuccessful() + "\n response: " + response);
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityUserInfo.this, "Upload Successful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                        JSONArray userInfoObject = jsonObject.getJSONArray("userInfo");
                        JSONObject userIDObject = userInfoObject.getJSONObject(0);
                        Long userId = userIDObject.getLong("userId");
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: 1.5: " + userId);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Log.d(TAG, "2. onResponse: 200: Upload Successful."
                           + " statusCode: " + response.body().getStatusCode()
                           + " statusMessage: " + response.body().getStatusMessage()
                           + " user ID: " + response.body().getUserId()
                           + "\n userInfo: " + response.body().getUserInfo().get(0));
                }
                else{
                    if(response.body() != null){
                        APIError apiError = ErrorUtils.parseError(response);
                        Toast.makeText(ActivityUserInfo.this, "3. Save not successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d(TAG, "3. onResponse: Save not successful"
                                +" ErrorUtils httpStatusCode: " + apiError.getHttpStatusCode()
                                +" ErrorUtils customCode: " + apiError.getCustomCode()
                                +" ErrorUtils message: " + apiError.getMessage());
                    }
                    else{
                        Log.d(TAG, "4. onResponse: response.body() is null");

                    }
                }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UserInfoModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "4. onFailure: t: " + t + " message: " + t.getMessage() + " toString: " + t.toString()
                    + " getCause: " + t.getCause() + " getStackTrace: " + t.getStackTrace());
            Toast.makeText(ActivityUserInfo.this, "Please check you internet connection.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Thanks for the help!

Comment: what is your base URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1st problem: How to get a value for the key "userId" from the API JSON response.

retrofit can automatically convert a JSON object into a POJO. so you just need to make your model classes.
for your JSON result, you need 2 model classes.

RootModel class

```
data class RootModel (
    var userInfo: mutableList<UserInfoChild> = ArrayList(),
    var statusCode: String = "",
    var statusMessage: String = ""
)
```

UserInfoChild class

```
data class UserInfoChild (
    var userId: Int = 0,
    var userName: String? = "",
    var userPassword: String? = ""
    // add other fields
)
```

next, change `Call<UserInfoModel>` to `Call<RootModel>`

in the end, in the `onResponse` method you can easily access to `userId` field.

```
val userId = response.body().userInfo[0].userId
```

---

> 2nd problem: status code is 500

use two backslashes in your URL may be the answer. if you share your base URL, then it'll be easier to solve it

Answer (score 1):

You will need to break your `UserInfoModel` model class into two: one class to represent the "outer" object (with `userInfo`, `statusCode`, and `statusMessage`) and one class to represent the items in the array.

```
public class UserInfoResponse {

    private List<UserInfoItem> userInfo;
    private int statusCode;
    private String statusMessage;

    // ...
}
```

```
public class UserInfoItem {

     private String userFullName;
     private String userPassword;
     private String userName;

     // ...
}
```

You'll now make `Call<UserInfoResponse>` calls, and access the items in the list like this:

```
UserInfoResponse response = // ...
String name = response.getUserInfo()[0].getUserName();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ben P. Your solution is absolutely correct as is the one above. 
Just for clarification to others, i also created the getters in Root and Child Models and later in the onResponse the following code to get the userId:
    
            response.body().getUserInfo().get(0).getUserId()

Comment: Remind that `userInfoList` should rename to `userInfo`. if not u have to use `@SerializedName`.

Answer (score 0):

My question had two problems: Problem 1 was solved by both hassan and Ben.
As for the Problem 2 how do decode the response in case isSuccessful is false, i had to use the response.errorBody() instead of response.body() as the later was always null in my case for isSuccessful = false.
The following code helped from this post: [Getting json from retrofit's response errorBody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42629992/getting-json-from-retrofits-response-errorbody)

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
try {
    APIError errorResponse = gson.fromJson(response.errorBody().string(),APIError.class);

    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: message: " + errorResponse.getMessage()
    + " httpStatusCode: " + errorResponse.getHttpStatusCode()
    + " customCode: " + errorResponse.getCustomCode()
    );
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Where APIError.java is a class for return model in case of error, similar to root model suggested by both hassan and Ben:

```
public class APIError {
private int httpStatusCode;
private String customCode, message = "Unknown error.";

public APIError() {
}

public int getHttpStatusCode() {
    return httpStatusCode;
}

public String getCustomCode() {
    return customCode;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

}
```